# How do I create my first map?

Tags: qgis

I am new to GIS and am trying to create my first map.

Could anyone recomend any good tutorials which are clear and simple? I am having difficulty importing my open source map information into my QGIS propgram. (I have had a look at the tutorial and online)

Comment: Describe what data you have, and what map you're trying to make...Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html?

Comment: What about the tutorial wasn't clear?  What sort of problems have you encountered?  As written this question is really too broad for us to answer...